# Two players battleship with one board from text file input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently struggling with a uni assignment! The task is to create an alternative to the famous battleship game: two players play on the same board and guess turn by turn where the ships are placed. The winner is the one with the highest point count (every hit is a point).

However, in order to set up the ships and the board dimension, we need to parse a text file having the following structure :

```
8
Ship1;3\*3;3\*2;3\*1
Ship2;6\*1;5\*1;4\*1
etc...
```

I am trying to use the scanner with a delimiter, but we have two kinds of delimiter here, which causes me problems...
I can't find how to use the scanner to get the info of the text file into variables in java.

In the text file, 8 is the length of the board (it is a square) and the other numbers are the coordinates associated with a ship

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: In the classic [Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) game, the columns are identified by letters and the rows by numbers so that `A1` is the top, left square of the board. Your text file seems to contain different coordinates. Please [edit] your question and explain how to interpret the coordinates in the text file that you need to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `Scanner` objects:

```
String line = "Ship1;3\\*3;3\\*2;3\\*1";
Scanner outer = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s*;\\s*");
while (outer.hasNext()) {
    if (outer.next().equals("Ship"))
        continue; 
    Scanner inner = new Scanner(outer.next()).useDelimiter("\\s*\\*\\s*");
    while (inner.hasNext())
        inner.next(); //store this somewhere
}
```

The first `Scanner` returns the coordinates of a point. The second scanner extracts the x and y coordinate.

Since there will always be only two coordinates and each coordinate has only one digit, you could use a much simpler code, with a loss of generality.

```
int[][] output = new int[3][2]; \\1st index for coordinate. 2nd index for x or y
byte ctr = 0;
outer.next(); //disregarding "Ship1"
while (outer.hasNext()) {
    String coordinate = outer.next();
    output[ctr][0] = coordinate.charAt(0) - 48;
    output[ctr][1] = coordinate.charAt(3) - 48;
    ++ctr;
}
```

Where `outer` is as defined in the previous snippet.
Here outer.next() returns, say, `3\*3`. I have simply taken ony the characters at the 1st and 3rd index of this string.
I have subtracted 48 from each character, because the ASCII value for `'0'` is 48.